# [C++/WinRT]How to access Event Handler (reaction of button clicking) from function and not by clicking. (Speech Operation)

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, c++-winrt

Recently I am trying to use my voice to control buttons in C++/WinRT with Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognizer class. But when I bind the speech recognizer to an event, it only give two parameters that are relative recognition result. If I wanna activate button, it seems that I need to pass other two parameters in order to activate my button..
Here's my code.

Cpp file.

```
 winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::MicInitial(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    

  m_speechRecognizer_en = Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognizer();
  auto session1 = m_speechRecognizer_en.ContinuousRecognitionSession();
  winrt::event_token taskRequestedToken = session1.ResultGenerated({ this, &MainPage::OnResultGenerated });
  std::vector<winrt::hstring> speechCommandList_en;       
  speechCommandList_en.push_back(L"button open");


    Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognitionListConstraint spConstraint_en = Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(speechCommandList_en); 
    auto constraints_en = m_speechRecognizer_en.Constraints();
    constraints_en.Clear();
    constraints_en.Append(spConstraint_en);

    
    //TODO 
    co_await winrt::resume_background();
    auto result_en = m_speechRecognizer_en.CompileConstraintsAsync().get(); 
    co_await ui_thread;

    if (result_en.Status() == Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognitionResultStatus::Success)
    {

        auto task = session1.StartAsync();

    }
}

    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::OnResultGenerated(Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession const& sender, Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs const& args)
{
    auto rec_confidence = args.Result().Confidence();
    if (rec_confidence == Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognitionConfidence::High || rec_confidence == Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition::SpeechRecognitionConfidence::Medium)
    {
        winrt::hstring words = args.Result().Text();


        if (words == L"button open")
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------
            ClickHandlerOpen();//<-----Don't know what to do with this 
           //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        }
        co_await winrt::resume_background();//
        co_await winrt::resume_foreground(greetingOutput().Dispatcher());

        greetingOutput().Text(L"Recognize: " + words + L"!");

    }
}


 winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::ClickHandlerOpen(
    IInspectable const&,
    Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
      ........................
}
```

Could someone help me solve this problem? Thank you a lot!!

Comment: The way you wrote it,  takes two parameters which are ignored. So pass two parameters which will be ignored. You may need to switch to a foreground thread if `ClickHandlerOpen` requires it.

Comment: Hi @RaymondChen , thanks for your replying. Actually, I observe your speech recognition sample and translated the useful parts into C++/WinRT, it really helps a lot! Back to my problem, what you say is create meaningless IInspectable and RoutedEventArgs in the OnResultGenerated function and pass those two parameter at ClickHandlerOpen()?

Comment: This is just a computer programming question unrelated to C++/WinRT. You want to call a function that takes two parameters. So call it with two parameters. If you would rather call it with no parameters, then write an alternative version of the function that takes no parameters.

Comment: Hi @RaymondChen, thank for replying. But I have multiple buttons, which means I have to duplicate them all........Is there any way that I can pass two more parameters when binding events?

Comment: You mean, like, default arguments? Yes, C++ supports [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments). Which brings you back to the initial problem: You'll need to invent two values that can be ignored. Side node: Do not ever pass references into co-routines. They'll die behind your back.